# IBM MobileFirst 7.1 Server connection fails in Android after migrating from WL6.3

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I have an IBM Worklight 6.3 project which works without any problem. I received a ticket from Google, telling me that I need to update to the most recent version or the app will be taken down from the PlayStore.

After doing the corresponding update to MobileFirst7.1 on Eclipse without manually changing any file, I am trying to run the app in my own local server. It works fine using all preview tools and even using XCode iphone 6 emulator. However, when I try to run the app in a real Android device, it does not connect to the server.

I've already:

- Changed server configuration from localhost to my computer ip address.
- Changed Build settings and deploy target to my computer ip address.
- Connected both devices to the same wireless network.
- Installed all fixpacks available.
- Connected to server URL from android's device browser correctly.

While monitoring the network, I could also notice that no traffic is coming from the application. When connecting directly from the browser I can see the packages being sent to the server, but while opening the app nothing happens.

I have debugged WL.Device.Network and everything seems normal:

```
{"isNetworkConnected":"true","isAirplaneMode":"false","isRoaming":"false", "networkConnectionType":"WIFI",...}
```

but WL.Client.Connect is returning this:

```
{"status":-1,"errorCode":null,"errorMsg":null}
```

The port I'm using for local server is the default 10080.

Does anyone know what's happenning?

EDIT:

I'm Adding LogCat messages (errors and warnings):

> 05-12 10:27:17.279: W/WLClient(23424): WLClient.createInstance in WLClient.java:225 :: You should pass a context that is assignable from the Activity class. WLClient instance may be used to start an activity.
>
> 05-12 10:27:19.142: W/cr_media(23424): Requires BLUETOOTH permission
>
> 05-12 10:27:19.567: W/cr_AwContents(23424): onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
>
> 05-12 10:27:20.136: E/libEGL(23424): validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
>
> 05-12 10:27:20.203: W/cr_BindingManager(23424): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 23424
>
> 05-12 10:27:20.255: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(23424): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/default/js/messages.js
>
> 05-12 10:27:21.243: W/ContextImpl(23424): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/com.myApp/files
>
> 05-12 10:27:21.249: W/ContextImpl(23424): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/com.myApp/cache
>
> 05-12 10:27:21.268: W/ContextImpl(23424): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/com.myApp/files
>
> 05-12 10:27:21.276: W/ContextImpl(23424): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/com.myApp/files
>
> 05-12 10:27:21.282: W/ContextImpl(23424): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/com.myApp/cache
>
> 05-12 10:27:21.619: W/cr_BindingManager(23424): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 23424
>
> 05-12 10:27:23.054: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(23424): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/messages/es-CO/messages.json
>
> 05-12 10:27:23.186: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(23424): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/default/images/favicon.png
>
> 05-12 10:27:23.332: W/ContextImpl(23424): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/com.myApp/files
>
> 05-12 10:27:23.348: W/ContextImpl(23424): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/com.myApp/files
>
> 05-12 10:27:23.359: W/ContextImpl(23424): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/com.myApp/cache
>
> 05-12 10:27:23.454: W/PluginManager(23424): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Globalization.getLocaleName blocked the main thread for 28ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
>
> 05-12 10:27:23.729: W/PluginManager(23424): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to DeviceAuth.getDeviceUUID blocked the main thread for 207ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
>
> 05-12 10:27:23.832: W/Settings(23424): Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
>
> 05-12 10:27:24.260: W/cr_BindingManager(23424): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 23424
>
> 05-12 10:27:24.293: W/cr_BindingManager(23424): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 23424
>
> 05-12 10:27:24.298: W/cr_BindingManager(23424): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 23424
>
> 05-12 10:27:24.306: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(23424): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/default/images/favicon.png
>
> 05-12 10:27:24.306: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(23424): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/default/images/favicon.png
>
> 05-12 10:27:24.308: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(23424): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/default/images/favicon.png
>
> 05-12 10:27:24.446: W/Settings(23424): Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
>
> 05-12 10:27:24.769: W/PluginManager(23424): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to LoggerPlugin.log blocked the main thread for 68ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
>
> 05-12 10:27:24.800: W/NONE(23424): Note that if your application targets Android 3.0 (API level 11) or higher, WL.OptionsMenu might have no effect, depending on the device.
>
> 05-12 10:27:24.859: W/PluginManager(23424): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to LoggerPlugin.log blocked the main thread for 33ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
>
> 05-12 10:27:24.890: W/PluginManager(23424): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to LoggerPlugin.log blocked the main thread for 19ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
>
> 05-12 10:27:25.308: W/PluginManager(23424): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to NetworkDetector.getNetworkInfo blocked the main thread for 45ms. Plugin should use 
>   CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
>
> 05-12 10:27:25.343: W/Settings(23424): Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
>
> 05-12 10:27:25.894: E/NONE(23424): [/apps/services/api/myApp/android/init] failure. state: -1, response: undefined
>
> 05-12 10:27:25.908: E/NONE(23424): [/apps/services/api/myApp/android/query] failure. state: -1, response: undefined
>
> 05-12 10:27:25.921: E/NONE(23424): [/apps/services/api/myApp/android/query] failure. state: -1, response: undefined

Comment: Well, what do you see in LogCat after launching the application and letting it run? provide the log.

Comment: Thanks for your help Idan, i have edited the question to add the LogCat errors and warnings, I hope now you can come up to a better understanding of the situation.

Comment: Something's very wrong in your app... 1) are you sure it passed migration correctly? 2) does it work with a *new* app that only performs WL.Client.connect call?

Comment: 1) I migrated the war file using the ant task suggested by IBM, then I opened the 6.3 file in Eclipse with 7.1, it started loading, and then the message "project was successfuly migrated from x to x" appeared on the console. I guess it was correct.

2) It works, I just tested a new blank project and WL.Client.Connect is working.

Comment: Why did you "migrate the war file" if you are testing this in Studio? This is done for you by Studio. You can also try to delete the "native folder" and rebuild the app. Also note that you have no reason to move to 7.1 just because of Google warnings. You need only to install the latest 6.3 studio...

Answer (score 0):

> I have an IBM Worklight 6.3 project which works without any problem. I received a ticket from Google, telling me that I need to update to the most recent version or the app will be taken down from the PlayStore.

You are not required to upgrade to MFP 7.1 in order to resolve warnings sent by Google.

If you are not equipped just yet make a massive change from 6.3 to 7.1, simply go to IBM Fix Central and download the latest 6.3 iFix, which fixes all known and current Google warnings. Re-build and re-publish your app on to the Google App Store.